# Compare column of datatable with if statement

Tags: c#, winforms, csv, ado.net, datatable

I need to import the CSV file then upload into the Datatable. Then I need to verify the column to meet requirements and make sure the end user import with correct format. In the CSV file must have 3 column namely item, price and measure.

The error begin when I trying to compare the column name with string, here the code snippet.

```
private bool verifyColumn(DataTable dt)
{
    /* Column 
     * 1) items
     * 2) price
     * 3) measure
    */

    foreach (DataColumn col in dt.Columns)
    {  
        if (col.ColumnName.ToString() == "price")
        {
            continue;
        }
        else if (col.ColumnName.ToString() == "item")
        {
            continue;
        }
        else if (col.ColumnName.ToString() == "measure")
        {
            continue;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }                           
    }

    return true;
}
```

When debugging mode, for the first loop is show 'item' but cannot catch in the if statement. How can I resolved this things?

Code to import CSV file into the datatable by using [A Portable and Efficient Generic Parser for Flat Files](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/11698/A-Portable-and-Efficient-Generic-Parser-for-Flat-F).

```
GenericParserAdapter paste = new GenericParserAdapter(fileName);                    
paste.FirstRowHasHeader = true;
paste.ColumnDelimiter = ';';

DataTable dt dt = paste.GetDataTable();
if (dt.Columns.Count != 3)
{ 
    MessageBox.Show(errorMessage, this.Text, MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
    dt.Clear();
    return;
}

// Here to do verify columт
```

Answer (score 0):

It appears to me that the first column was "items", but you filter by "item".

P/S: you should create a variable to hold the col.ColumnName.ToString() value. (given the ColumnName is not string, which is a little bit strange)